# Proving (or disproving) that a set of random variables is a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> A fair coin is tossed repeatedly with results $Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ...$ that are 0 or 1 with probability $1/2$ each. For $n \geq 1$ let $X_n  = Y_n + Y_{n-1}$ be the number of 1's in the $(n-1)$th and $n$th tosses. Is $X_n$ a Markov chain?

I've just gotten into Stochastic Processes and Markov chains and thus am a little unfamiliar - I know that, by definition, a Markov chain must be such that the probability of an event happening depends only on the previous state, and thus can be written in a probability matrix of the form $P(i, j)$.

Here, however, it doesn't seem that the probability of the event in state $n$ depends not only on state $n-1$, but also on state $n$ itself - does this mean that this is not a Markov chain? If it is, I'm not sure how the probability matrix would look.

Comment: For a Markov chain, the probability to be in a given state $i$ at time $n$ should depend only on $i$ and the state at time $n-1$. Thus here you need to check whether $P(X_n=i \mid X_{n-1}=j)$ depends only on $i,j$ for $i,j=0,1,2$ (9 combinations) Hint: notice that $X_{n-1}=1$ can happen in two different ways. Does the choice of which way it happens affect the distribution of $X_n$?

Comment: @Ian I believe that the way in which $X_{n-1}$ = 1 does affect the distribution of $X_n$. 

For example, if it was the case that $Y_{n-2}$ = 0 and $Y_{n-1}$ = 1, then $P(X_n = 2 | X_{n-1} = 1)$ = 1/2. However, if $Y_{n-2}$ = 1 and $Y_{n-1}$ = 0, then $P(X_n = 2 | X_{n-1} = 1)$ = 0. Thus, this wouldn't be a Markov chain. Is this correct?

Comment: @mizichael It's perfectly fine for $X_{n-1}$ to influence $X_n$. It's not OK for any state other than the most recent one to affect $X_n$

Comment: @Ian so here, if we know the value of $X_{n-1}$ and $Y_{n-1}$, we must know the probability of $X_n$ taking any given value. Thus, it must be a Markov chain. How would this probability matrix look?

Comment: @Ian I guess the thing that confuses me most is the conditional probability statement - we can certainly write that $P(X_n = i | Y_{n-1} = j, Y_{n-1} = k, ...)$ = $P(X_n = i | Y_{n-1} = j)$. However, we can't really write that $P(X_n = i | X_{n-1} = j, X_{n-2} = k, ...)$ = $P(X_n = i | X_{n-1} = j)$, can we?

Comment: @mizichael Your second conditional probability equation with only $X_i$ is correct and the only one of the two that is relevant (you've stated the Markov property and that is the only requirement for a stochastic process to be a Markov process. Note that authors disagree on the specific definition of a Markov **chain**, so you should check any texts you are working from for the precise definition of the chain. But as for the Markov property, your example definitely has it, and the Markov property has nothing to do with $Y_i$, only on $X_i$ in this case.

Comment: @Ian it's very possible I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around a simple problem, but I'm still a bit confused. What is the probability that $X_n$ = $0$ given $X_{n-1}$ = $1$?

Comment: I'm actually wrong about the Markov property (see Ian's answer)

Answer (score 3):

$X_n$ is not Markov. Consider for illustration $P(X_3=2 \mid X_2=1,X_1=0)$ vs. $P(X_3=2 \mid X_2=1,X_1=2)$. In the first case, you know from $X_1=0$ that $Y_1=0$. So since $X_2=1$, $Y_2=1$. So the desired probability is $P(Y_3=1)=1/2$.

In the second case, you know from $X_1=2$ that $Y_1=1$. So since $X_2=1$, $Y_2=0$. Thus this probability is zero.

Intuitively, the issue here is that the information "$X_{n-1}=1$" does not give you complete information about what $Y_{n-1}$ was, whereas additional information about older values of $X_n$ can do that. If instead you are given $X_{n-1}=0$ or $X_{n-1}=2$ then you get what $Y_{n-1}$ was, which is enough to pin everything down.

Comment: This makes perfect sense - sorry for not understanding right away, I'm still very new to these concepts and thus what is and isn't "allowed" in these definitions. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @mizichael You're welcome. This stuff can be subtle, in part because the formalism and the intuition don't mesh quite perfectly some of the time.

Answer (score 2):

In a first order Markov chain, $X_{n-1}$ and $X_{n+1}$ are conditionally independent given $X_n$. That is, the function $p(x,y,z)=P((X_{n-1},X_n,X_{n+1}) = (x,y,z)$ factors into a product of form $A(y)B(x,y)C(y,z)$.  (This is equivalent to the condition stated in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property) which implies a factorization of form $p(x,y,z)=a(x)b(x,y)c(y,z)$; these are the same on setting $A(y)B(x,y)=a(x)b(x,y)$.) But a tabulation of all 16 possible $(Y_{n-2},Y_{n-1},Y_n,Y_{n+1})$ values yields the following values for $p(x,1,z))$, namely:
$$(p(x,1,z)=\begin{pmatrix}0&1/8&1/8\\1/8&2/8&1/8\\1/8&1/8&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ The factorization property would say that $p(x,1,z)=A(1)B(x,1)C(1,z)$, which is to say the above matrix has rank 1. But it obviously has rank 2.  That is, conditional on $X_n=1$, the immediate past and future $X_{n-1}$ and $X_{n+1}$ are *not* independent.  The $X_n$ chain is not first order Markov.

This is intuitively obvious: the sequences `010` and `212` cannot appear in the $X_n$ stream, even though all the 2-long subsequences `01`, `10`, `12`, and `21` can.  A first order Markov chain is not smart enough to make this happen.

Comment: Hey @kimchi lover I am looking over markov related material for the first time. Where can i learn about introductory stochastic processes from a more "sophisticated" POV, as in your post?

Comment: Any serious upper division undergraduate textbook in probability theory should do the trick.  I learned from Feller's *Introduction to probability theory and its applications* and Karlin & Taylor's *First course in stochastic processes*, but many excellent books have been written since then.  The one by Grimmett is very good.